# JAXB Map with abstract class values

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, abstract-class

I have the following Map that contains either Double or Integer instances  as value, both of which extend the abstract class Number, annotated as follows:

```
@XmlElement(name="settings")
private Map<String,Number> settings;
```

It's marshalled into XML as:

```
<settings>
    <entry>
        <key>SETTING_A</key>
        <value xsi:type="xs:double">0.03</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <key>SETTING_B</key>
        <value xsi:type="xs:int">1000</value>
    </entry>
</settings>
```

I also need to provide the XSD for this type of XML, and here is where I have problems. I tried to define a complexType with a choice, but doesn't work because the  element that contain the int, and the element that contains the double can't have the same name (ie. they can't be both named "value"), which is exactly what the JAXB generated XML does.

The following XSD would work, but I don't want to have different element names ( or ):

```
<xsd:complexType name="Entry">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="key" type="NimrodSettingKey" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:choice>
           <xsd:element name="double" type="xsd:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xsd:element name="int" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Any suggestions on how should I specify that the  element could be an int or a double in my XSD document?

Thanks!

**EDIT #1**

@svasa suggested using the following approach in my XSD, which give the same name to an element inside a choice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="Settings"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Settings">
   <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:choice>
          <xsd:element name="value" xs:type="xsi:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
          <xsd:element name="value" xs:type="xsi:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

but my XSD editor complained with this error:

```
complex type 'Settings' violates the unique particle attribution rule in its components 'value' and 'value'
```

which I think means that the two elements under the  must have different names each, they can't both be named "value".

Comment: By `the values that contain an int and those that contain a number can't have the same name` do you mean the `key` cannot have same name for `int` and `double` right?

Comment: Yes, for instance key=SETTING_A value=0.5d (a double) and key=SETTING_B value=1000 (and int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for refactoring my code from:

```
@XmlElement(name="settings")
private Map<String,Number> settings
```

to:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="settings")
@XmlElement(name="setting")
private List<Setting> settings;
```

My Settings class was renamed to Setting and now stores one single setting with attributes:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="name")
private String name;

@XmlAttribute(name="intValue")
private Integer intValue;

@XmlAttribute(name="doubleValue")
private Double doubleValue;
```

And when marshalled into XML, it produces the  elements that either have doubleValue or intValue attributes (but the element is named  in both cases):

```
<settings>
   <setting name="SETTING_A" doubleValue="1.0E-5"/>
   <setting name="SETTING_B" intValue="1000"/>
   ...
</settings>
```

And the XML generated is valid when the XSD contains:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Settings">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="setting" type="Setting" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Setting">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="doubleValue" type="xsd:double"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="intValue" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem of the `name` being same for double and int ?

Comment: @svasa In the original question, I didn't want to have XML elements with different names (ie. <int> and <double>) in my XSD. In my own answer, I opted to have an XML element named <setting> that has attributes named doubleValue and intValue (which is fine in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The `xs:choice` should enable you to specify integer or double, and `maxOccurs="1"` will take care of only one value.

But if you want the `key` to be unique, you could use xsd:unique like below:

```
<xsd:element name="settings">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="entry">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="key" type="NimrodSettingKey" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="value" xsi:type="xsd:double" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element name="value" xsi:type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
              </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:unique name="keyU">
         <xsd:selector xpath=".//key" />
         <xsd:field xpath="." />
    </xsd:unique>
  </xsd:element>
```

This section :

```
<xsd:unique name="keyU">
      <xsd:selector xpath=".//key" />
      <xsd:field xpath="." />
</xsd:unique>
```

adds an [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_unique.asp) that specifies your `key`s should be unique.

Comment: This solution gives me an error (see original question **EDIT #1**), apparently the elements under the <choice> can't have the same name (that's why I had named them as "double" and "int" in the original post).